# Shuffle specific DataTable column values

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to shuffle DataTable column values. My table looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|   11 |   12 |   13 |   14 |   15 |
|   21 |   22 |   23 |   24 |   25 |
|   31 |   23 |   33 |   34 |   25 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Now, what I would like to happen is to shuffle the cell values of **col2**, **col3**, and **col4** randomly. Example:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|   11 |   14 |   12 |   13 |   15 |
|   21 |   23 |   24 |   22 |   25 |
|   31 |   32 |   34 |   33 |   35 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

This is my code so far.

```
private void shuffleDT()
{
    DataTable sdt = new DataTable();

    sdt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
    sdt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
    sdt.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
    sdt.Columns.Add("col4", typeof(string));
    sdt.Columns.Add("col5", typeof(string));

    sdt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" });
    sdt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "21", "22", "23", "24", "25" });
    sdt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "31", "32", "33", "34", "35"});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `Random`

```
private DataTable sdt = new DataTable();

private void InitDt()
{
    sdt = new DataTable();

    sdt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
    sdt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
    sdt.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
    sdt.Columns.Add("col4", typeof(string));
    sdt.Columns.Add("col5", typeof(string));

    sdt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" });
    sdt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "21", "22", "23", "24", "25" });
    sdt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "31", "23", "33", "34", "25" });
}

private void ShuffleDT()
{
    Random loRan = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    int lnRan;
    string[] loRowValues = new string[3];
    List<int> loList;

    foreach (DataRow loRow in sdt.Rows)
    {
        loList = new List<int>();
        while (loList.Count < 3)
        {
            if (loList.Count == 2)
                loList.Add(new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2 }.Except(loList).First());
            else
            {
                lnRan = loRan.Next(0, 3);
                if (!loList.Contains(lnRan))
                    loList.Add(lnRan);
            }
        }

        loRowValues[0] = loRow.Field<string>(1);
        loRowValues[1] = loRow.Field<string>(2);
        loRowValues[2] = loRow.Field<string>(3);

        loRow.SetField<string>(1, loRowValues[loList[0]]);
        loRow.SetField<string>(2, loRowValues[loList[1]]);
        loRow.SetField<string>(3, loRowValues[loList[2]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. This code works. But what if i add more columns that I wanted to shuffle? Thanks!

Comment: Then you have to add parameters to the method (indexFrom, indexTo). These must considered in the while loop.